# Preserve names when factorizing a character variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stata

I have `df` like this one:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~country, ~status,
  "American Samoa", "non-UN member",
  "Argentina", "UN member",
  "Austria", "UN member",
  "Canada", "UN member",
  "Norfolk Island", "AU Territory",
  "Martinique", "FR Territory"
)
```

I would like to have new column, `fac1`, which have levels and names at the same time (kind of like a attribute for a column). It seems though that in R we only could have one of these:

we lost **names** in this case:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    fac1 = as.integer(factor(status)),
    fac2 = ifelse(fac1 == 4, 1, 0)
  )
```

and here we lost **factor** level:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    fac1 = factor(status),
    fac2 = ifelse(fac1 == "UN member", 1, 0)
  )
```

The ultimate goal for me is like to have R codes same as `Stata` syntax below:
In `stata`, there is an option to have a new column based on character variable while the character names and level are both stored and preserved. The syntax is like below:

```
encode status, gen(fact1)
gen fact2= 1 if fact1 == 4
```

Comment: I don't understand. `fac1` in your 2nd example is a factor, and you can examine its labels, as you did, or its levels, eg. with `fac3 = ifelse(as.numeric(fac1) == 1, 1, 0)`. It has both. The `AU Territory` label goes with level 1, since these are by default set in alphabetical order or the unique values of the factor.

Comment: Your factor already has levels and names at the same time. Thats why its considered as a factor and not a character.

Comment: I think it might be helpful if you mentioned why you want to add the new column with levels and names. Because that way, there might be an easier way to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish without having to create columns.